# Jinja load template from string - and extend from file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I have the following code:

```
from jinja2 import Template
templ_str = "lots of garbly html" # Compiled by external logic
templ_context = ast.literal_eval(context_dir)  # Compiled by external logic
template = Template(templ_str)
template.render(**context)
```

The body of the template is compiled on the fly and passed to the template engine. However, I would like to extend that template with a basic wrapper, from a file. I know this can be done with FileSystemLoader, but I need to load my main template from memory, not from a file.

From the API documentation, it seems like this is not doable. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just use a `ChoiceLoader` for this? Put your generated template in a `DictLoader`, then setup the `ChoiceLoader` with the `DictLoader` and an appropriate `FileSystemLoader`.